# Rbenv says Ruby 2.1.2 isn't installed even after I installed it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

When I used rails s to initiate the Rails server I get this.

```
➜  zumin-share git:(master) rails s

rbenv: version `2.1.2' is not installed (set by /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/.ruby-version)
```

I then try to install rbenv 2.1.2 and the installer should be finished. I checked Rbenv version and I get.

```
rbenv version

2.1.2 (set by /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/.ruby-version)
```

I thought it was the .ruby-version file giving me trouble and when I removed it I get.

```
rails s

/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/smart_listing-1.0.0/lib/smart_listing/config.rb:73: warning: duplicated key at line 79 ignored: :href
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ansi-1.4.3/lib/ansi/chart.rb:26: warning: duplicated key at line 29 ignored: :concealed
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/config.ru:in `new'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/config.ru:in `<main>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/bin/rails:8:in `require'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/ericxavierdoyle/Eric_Dev/ElliotWhyte/zumin-share/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:3:in `load'
  from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try opening a new terminal window and see if you are still experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: I just did that and I'm still getting the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your .ruby-version file is used by rbenv to detect what version of Ruby to use(besides looking in this file rbenv also looks in RBENV_VERSION environment variable if it's specified, and some other files). So in your case specified Ruby version was 2.1.2 and since it's not installed on your system rbenv complained about that, but since rbenv looks on few other places to detect what version of Ruby to use it found some other version and used it to run your code.
After installing version 2.1.2 your system now have version defined in your .ruby-version and rbenv will use it to run your code, but since your gems are installed for version of Ruby that you were using before 2.1.2 you'll get errors. At least I think that's what is going on, it would be great if some experienced programmer can comment on this.